# Redirect output of console to a file on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

Say I have a website that return me **JSON** data when I send a **GET** request using **curl**. I want to re-direct the output of curl to **AWS S3**. A new file should be created on S3 for it.

Currently I am able to redirect the output to store it locally.

```
curl -s -X GET 'http://website_that_returns_json.com' > folder_to_save/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M.json")
```

I have `AWS CLI` and `s3cmd` installed. How would I redirect the output of create to create a new file on AWS S3 ?

**Assume :**

1. AWS S3 access key and secret key are already set.
2. Location to store file : `mybucket/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M.json"`

Comment: One way I can think of is to save the file locally and then use - `aws s3 cp local_copy s3_path`. But is there an efficient way (not saving an intermediate file) to do this ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has the ability to [stream data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html?highlight=stream) to/from Amazon S3:

> The following `cp` command uploads a local file stream from standard input to a specified bucket and key:

```
aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/stream.txt
```

So, you could use:

```
curl xxx | aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/object.txt
```

However, it's probably safer to save the file locally and then copy it to Amazon S3.

Comment: Sidenote: It is also possible to use Amazon's CLI with other S3 compatible services using the `--endpoint-url <server URL>` flag. Also, it appears like this tool properly streams the file to the server without caching the whole file in memory first, which is important for large files.

Comment: It works in reverse too! You can use `-` as the output file to read a file. I use it to view gzipped SQL backups like this: `aws s3 cp "s3://bucket_where_I_keep_db_backups/Sat Oct 13 23:53:27 UTC 2018.sql.gz" - | gzip -d | less`

Comment: @John Rotenstein is there any data limit, can I redirect like 1GB of data as stream to `aws s3 cp -`?

Comment: @Vishrant Yes, most probably. It simply uses stdin/stdout instead of a file.

Answer (score 1):

In case you'd like to run the command on the remote, use `aws ssm send-command`.

Then to redirect the output of that command to S3, you can use `--output-s3-bucket-name` parameter.

Here is Bash script to run PowerShell script on the remote and upload it into S3 bucket:

```
instanceId="i-xyz"
bucketName="bucket_to_save"
bucketDir="folder_to_save"
command="Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri http://example.com).Content"
cmdId=$(aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "$instanceId" --document-name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" --query "Command.CommandId" --output text  --output-s3-bucket-name "$bucketName" --output-s3-key-prefix "$bucketDir" --parameters commands="'${command}'")
while [ "$(aws ssm list-command-invocations --command-id "$cmdId" --query "CommandInvocations[].Status" --output text)" == "InProgress" ]; do sleep 1; done
outputPath=$(aws ssm list-command-invocations --command-id "$cmdId" --details --query "CommandInvocations[].CommandPlugins[].OutputS3KeyPrefix" --output text)
echo "Command output uploaded at: s3://${bucketName}/${outputPath}"
aws s3 ls "s3://${bucketName}/${outputPath}"
```

To output the uploaded S3 files, run:

```
aws s3 ls s3://${bucketName}/${outputPath}/stderr.txt && aws s3 cp --quiet s3://${bucketName}/${outputPath}/stderr.txt /dev/stderr
aws s3 cp --quiet s3://${bucketName}/${outputPath}/stdout.txt /dev/stdout
```