# Redirect output along with error of console to a file on AWS S3 inside docker

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to find a way to re-direct the output as well as the errors to AWS S3 as a file inside docker. There are already some great answers in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284178/redirect-output-of-console-to-a-file-on-aws-s3).
Using the first answer given in the link I tried the following (outisde docker):

```
python3 train.py 2>&1 | aws s3 cp - s3://my_bucket_name/folder/output.log
```

This is working properly. The output.log file gets created in my s3 bucket as I intent to do. But when I put the same command as the CMD command inside Dockerfile it does nothing.

```
CMD python3 train.py 2>&1 | aws s3 cp - s3://my_bucket_name/folder/output.log
```

In fact docker kind of stuck and terminates after a while.

But, if I use the following code inside docker, the output gets created in the mount directory without any issue:

```
CMD python3 train.py > /mount/directory/output.log 2>&1
```

But I want the file uploaded to S3 live.

My use case:
I'm trying to train a deep learning model in an EC2 instance, but I want to somehow get whatever happening on the console as a log file and store it on S3 live. From S3 whenever a log file is uploaded lambda triggers and it sends that log file to the localhost/another server for some processing.

Also, is there any way to **show the output** in the main console along with the file being uploaded in S3?

P.S. I don't have a software background. I'm a mathematician trying to get in the field of deep learning. So, if I've framed the question wrong or used wrong terminologies pardon me.

Comment: `aws` cli should give error messages if it doesn't work.  Start by building the docker image and issuing a `docker run` command against the image, and run the `aws s3 cp` by hand with for a test.

Comment: @erik258 I'm not sure if I'm following you correctly. Did you mean try running an aws s3 cp command after running the docker image using interactive terminal like: "docker run --rm -it image_name bash" and then try running the same CMD command: " python3 train.py 2>&1 | aws s3 cp - s3://my_bucket_name/folder/output.log"? If yes, then I just tried it and it's working perfectly. Somehow it's not working as CMD command.

Comment: Docker's `CMD` does not execute in a shell, so shell specific commands and flags, like the pipe, will not work.  You need to explicitly run it in a shell with something like `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "python3 train.py 2>&1 | aws s3 cp - s3://my_bucket_name/folder/output.log"]`

Comment: @AnonCoward Thanks, it worked. But it's not redirecting the stream live. It's only uploading after the process/training is completed/interrupted. Is there any way to upload the console output to s3 from the start and keep updating it live? Also, could you please tell me how to view the output on the console as well along with this command so that I can understand what's happening behind the scenes?

Comment: You cannot use this command to update "live", S3 is an object storage system that does not allow modifications of current objects.  At best, you can upload and overwrite a new copy of the object with some frequency, but that requires custom code, and probably also involves a hefty bill.  If you want to both see the output and pipe it, [use the tee command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542522/best-way-to-tee-to-stdout-and-to-a-process)