# Stream stdout from a running AWS EC2 instance to a file in S3 (Linux bash)

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

So I'm running models on several EC2 Linux instances at once. The model is a black box binary that prints out it's progress to stdout as it runs. All EC2's have AWS CLI and are hooked up to an S3 bucket where they save the final results after their run, and then self terminate.

All I need to do is track the progress of each model as it runs. I'm launching these all from python, so they're randomly assigned an IP, and it would be overarchitecting to reserve a block of IP's to SSH into. So my aim is to simply stream their stdouts to a file on S3.

This should be the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/42285350, but it's not working for me. It only writes to the file once after the .sh is finished (the binary run is triggered inside run.sh).

`./run.sh | aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/pathto/results/results/progress.txt`

How do I get it to stream the stdout in realtime? I'm also hoping not to add much overhead which could increase simulation run times. Thanks

Comment: S3 objects can not be updated in real time, at best they can be recreated with new versions.  `aws s3 cp` creates on version of an object, so when feed streaming data, that object won't exist till the pipe is closed and the upload finished.  If you need real-time access to the logs as they update, you really should look into some other service.

Comment: You can use Cloudwatch agent. Also it will give you realtime view of your logs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html